# Relocating Floor Vent

Tags: hvac

We are looking to place window bench over a floor register and relocate the register to the front of the bench. Currently the floor vent is a 4"x10" opening. We are considering using flexible ducting to attach to front of bench and use a 2"x12" wall vent cover to be integrated with the bench trim. Are there significant issues with reducing the ventilation area from 4"x10" to 2"x12"?

Answer (score 1):

You're reducing the vent size by 40%. That will have a negative impact of the air flow in that room. It could also increase the sound level of the air leaving the smaller vent due to the increased pressure due to the smaller vent. I'd try to get a vent and duct closer to the original size.

Comment: One thing I have done in the past where I enclosed the area and had a “box” was to add multiple narrow vents on the bench but this depends on your plans but I would be cautious about reducing a vent close to a window, we put them there to off set the window.